# how to fix this problem Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript

how to fix this problem my code work in foreach loop then it's can work just first row and another row can not work. Show error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" can i fix?

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>

        function sum() {
       var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
       var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
       var txtforeNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt4').value;
       if (txtFirstNumberValue == "")
           txtFirstNumberValue = 0;
       if (txtSecondNumberValue == "")
           txtSecondNumberValue = 0;
      if (txtforeNumberValue == "")
            txtforeNumberValue = 0;

       var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) - parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
       var result_add = parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue) + parseInt(txtforeNumberValue);
       if (!isNaN(result)) {
           document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
           document.getElementById('txt5').value = result_add;
       }
   }
   </script>
```

```html
<td>
                          <label for="quantity">หน้าร้าน</label>
                          <input type="hidden" id="txt1" value="{{ $product->quantity_offline}}"  onkeyup="sum();" />
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity_offline" id="txt3" value="{{ $product->quantity_offline}}"  onkeyup="sum();" />
                             
                          </td> 
                          
                          <td>
                          <label for="quantity">โอน</label>
                          <img src="{{ asset('img/right-arrow.png') }}">
                          <input type="text" id="txt2" class="form-control" name="quantity_offline" onkeyup="sum();" />
                               

                          <td>
                          <label for="quantity">ออนไลน์</label>
                          <input type="hidden" id="txt4" value="{{ $product->quantity }}"  onkeyup="sum();" />
                              <input type="text" id="txt5" class="form-control" name="quantity" value="{{ $product->quantity }}"  onkeyup="sum();" />
                              
                          </td>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add the document that you are working with.

Comment: Please update your question so that the example works. Currently we get an error. But what your outlined error message suggests is that the element you want to use `addEventListener` on is `null`. Your code above does not have the line causing that issue. So please improve your question so that we can properly answer it. Thanks!

Comment: my html code is in foreach loop so is not working. Thanks!